# how to insert more densely sampled auxiliary variables into the georob package in Rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio

I need to make a prediction of a soil variable as a function of auxiliary variables in the georob package.

My solo dataset has 200 observations and my auxiliary variables set has 19940 data, however in the code, I can't enter the coordinates of the auxiliary variables as prediction points.

```
dat= read.csv("malhas amostrais/solo_200.csv", sep = ",")

covar = read.csv("../dados/csv/variaveis_auxiliares.csv", sep = ";")

ku_georob_cpeso <- georob(argila ~ CV + CH + dist_bebedouros + Eca_0.5m + Eca_1m + elevacao + IH_0.5m + sd_ndvi_01 + sd_ndvi_02 + twi + S_P_T + sd_b4 +sd_b5 + sd_b6+ sd_b7,
   data= dat,
   locations= ~ x + y,
   variogram.model="RMexp",
   param=c(variance=200, nugget=600, scale=150),
   verbose = 3,
   psi.func = "huber") 

ku_georob_cpeso <- georob(argila ~ CV + CH + dist_bebedouros + Eca_0.5m + Eca_1m + elevacao + IH_0.5m + sd_ndvi_01 + sd_ndvi_02 + twi + S_P_T + sd_b4 +sd_b5 + sd_b6+ sd_b7,
   data= dat1,
   subset = cova,
   locations= ~ x + y,
   variogram.model="RMexp",
   param=c(variance=200, nugget=600, scale=150),+ verbose = 3,
   psi.func = "huber")
```

I receive the error:

> Error in xj[i] : invalid subscript type 'list'